# How to save a thumbnail of a webpage?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I want to save a thumbnail of a webpage.So I creat a webview.The code is that

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
if (frame != [sender mainFrame]) {
    return;
}
    [sender lockFocus];
    NSData* data = [sender dataWithPDFInsideRect:[sender bounds]];
    [sender unlockFocus];
    NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    NSData* imageData = [img TIFFRepresentation];
    NSArray* deskTopArrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* deskTopPath = [deskTopArrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* pngPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/SaveWebThumbnail.png",deskTopPath];
    [imageData writeToFile:pngPath atomically:NO];
}
```

But there are some blank positions in the image that is saved.I don't know why? I guess that when the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: is called, the webview has not been really finished,isn't it? Anyone know the solusion,please tell me thank you!

Comment: `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` is called when the web page is finished *loading*, which doesn't mean it is finished *rendering*... Maybe you can add some arbitrary delay and hope it is done rendering by then, or inject JavaScript inside the page to notify you when it's done...

Comment: when the webpage is finished rending?